# Power BI : The relationship has cardinality Many-Many issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi, ssas, power-bi-report-server

I have a Power BI reporting project, where a many-to-many relationship exists between database tables. I have created a sales report where I have an SSAS Service as a link server in that ALL Database Views and functions are used to make Measures and KPI's.

Now we have a problem.
My Client needs Calendar format as 4-5-4. When we create a report with normal calendar format, I don't get any error while filtering the report but when I use a 4-5-4 calendar then my filters don't work and the core reason I found is a relation between the tables are not generating.

Please refer to the attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: As the error states the mapping you are trying to do does not make much sense, I can see month and year columns, if you also have the day then why don't you map the date from the sales with date from the calendar table.

Comment: Thanks Ajan Balankumaran , but i have weekly , daily ,quarterly ,monthly and year  filter where i cannot use dates is has to be filter according to week wise not date wise with calendar table

Comment: If you do a date-wise mapping you can filter by any level you have mentioned. The mapping has to be a one to many mapping where sales table should be many calendar table should be one. That is the mapping you require for your business case.

Comment: Hello ! I totally agree with Ajan. 
You can't let a many to many relationship between dates in these business case. 
Quick question: please, can you tell me what are columns "MonthWeekDays" and "WeekDays" ? They doesn't seem to change in the time .. When have you got a value = 2 ?